# Ruby: How to run all unit tests that I have in a folder with a single command?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I have, let's say:

```
emp_test.rb
sales_emp_test.rb
corporate_emp_test.rb
payroll_emp_test.rb
```

How can I run them all together? Should I include them into another test file?

I am using test/unit gem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create another ruby file and require all test files you want to run.

For example, I can create an `all.rb` file inside my `test` folder with this code:

```
Dir[File.dirname(File.absolute_path(__FILE__)) + '/**/*_test.rb'].each {|file| require file }
```

That would run every `*_test.rb` file found inside the `test` folder tree.

Run it with `ruby -Itest test/all.rb` from your project root.

Comment: assuming that the folder is called 'tests' and that all the files in it are tests, wouldn't be better to replace '/**/*_test.rb' with '/tests/*'?

Comment: That would mean that `all.rb` is placed on your project root, and not among the rest of the testing code. You can organize it however you want, of course. I prefer to have all my testing stuff inside my test folder. Also to assume that every file in there is a test, or is even ruby, is too risky on any of my projects.

Comment: Also changing `/**/*_test.rb` with `/tests/*` means you lose recurrency, but I guess that's not your point, right?

Comment: I understand what your point. I wanted to say that if you know that all the files inside the 'tests' folder are tests you do not need to look for the files that end in '_test.rb', right?

Comment: I need to do simple stuff at the moment. For this reason i'd like to keep it pretty and clear. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I just got what you meant. If I run all the files inside 'tests' I will re-run all.rb and I'll end into an infinite loop.